# TFS Build vnext build failing with no failed tests

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

My TFS builds seem to be failing intermittently and I can't figure out the reason quite yet.  It appears to be failing because of some kind of unit test failures but there aren't any failing tests that show up.  For example a build failure is reported and I see the following error:

`Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe failed with return code: 1
Vstest exited with return code: 1.`

Here is what I see in the test summary for this "failing" build:
[image: failed build]

Then I will see the same build succeed the next time it's ran with.  No new tests were added or deleted that triggered these builds:

[image]

Comment: select outcome all and inspect what happened in other 10. there might me a clue there. And does it really fail on testing step or in some other step in the build?

Comment: compare and find the 4 tests that succeeded in the second build but was not executed in the first.

Comment: @ChamindaC the 10 other tests are tests that are being skipped using the `[Ignore]` attribute

Comment: @ColeW It seems there are 4 tests not run in your first test, are you able to share the entire log of test step?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT the log for the test step is fairly long.  I have figured out which 4 tests are different between the failing build and the passing build but I'm not sure I see anything that helps me here.  Is there somewhere special you want me to post this log as it is fairly lengthy and I don't want to just include it in my post.

Comment: @ColeW would you be able to share the log over something like one drive or google drive. log of test execution would be enough i guess if it is failing in that step

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT here is the [failing test run](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ihyns539hakctqh/Failing%20Test%20Run.txt?dl=0).  Here is the [passing test run](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d91v5131j50wotr/Passing%20Test%20Run.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Did you use different build agent to run the testes?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT There are 2 available agents in the queue for this build and it does alternate between the 2.  It appears it fails on one of the agents but succeeds on another.  It may be just a coincidence and my lack of historical build data.  I am also using incremental builds to get better build speeds.

Comment: Is it always working on the second build agent? Can you reproduce the issue now?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT it appears to always be working on one test agent and failing on another.  I'm sure if I did clean builds every time this wouldn't happen but I'm not sure that is a solution.  I need these builds to be incremental for speed purposes.  I suppose I could add a clean build step upon build failures as well but I feel like this is more of a workaround than a solution.

Comment: When you run incremental build, are you able to find the 4 tests?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT the 4 tests that are different between the two builds are **VerifySingletonComposability**, **VerifySingletonComposability**,  **VerifyScaleComposability**, **VerifyScaleComposability**.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue. You may deploy the third build agent to see whether you can reproduce this issue.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT How would I go about adding a conditional build step to clean the build on failed builds?  I can try to reproduce it on a 3rd build agent but if that doesn't fail or even does fail I'm not sure where that gets me exactly.

Comment: On `Get resource` tab, there is a `clean` option, you can select `true` for this option.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I'm wanting to do this as a conditional build step so I don't have to do a clean build each time.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a build task after test task, and select condition `Run this task only when a previous task has failed`. Also, specify msbuild argument `/t:Clean` in this task to clean build:

[image]

Comment: I like the idea of this but what happens whenever you do something like delete a test project in an incremental build and it's no longer part of the solution.  My assumption here is that these dlls would still exist in the build output folders on the build server.  Would a manual delete task be better here?  I'm running my tests from the artifacts folder via: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\**\*.Test.dll`

Comment: You may add a `Delete files` task to delete files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=vsts